# Add new menu item action feature to 2sxc.org content toolbar

Tags: c#, razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Just getting to grips with this cool framework and interested in adding in an extra feature into the default toolbar. I assume the toolbar is from the following:

```
@Edit.Toolbar(Content)
```

And the functions from which each item is defined is in the 'inpage.js' file which houses all the menu item actions (add, new, replace). But when I try the following (inside in 'image max 3.cshtml'):

```
@Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions: "edit,replace,color");
```

and have a new colour action created in 'inpage.js':

```
'color': {
                title: "Toolbar.Sort",
                iclass: "icon-sxc-table",
                showOn: "edit",
                addCondition: function (settings, modConfig) { return modConfig.isList && settings.useModuleList && settings.sortOrder !== -1; }
            },
```

This however is not presenting anything to the screen for me. I assume I am missing something but my aim was to replicate the reorder feature action but instead have a modal popup colour palette in order to change the colour of the background of each indivudal 'Image(s) max 3. in a row' content type views.

Appreciate any and all help!

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2sxc 08.06 is out, and allows this now. Check out the 2sxc-wiki https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/Html-Js-Command-Custom-Code

Comment: Thx for this release, much appreciated! Question: Is it best to duplicate an existing template and insert a custom toolbar and if so what would be the best way to approach creating a custom toolbar? I have read over the Wiki pages (great amount there!) but just would like a little direction as to where to start. Will I edit inpage.js actions to include a new action? I read about including 'more' for advanced actions like actions: "develop,more". Thx again, Denis

Comment: To create custom buttons, DONT edit the inpage js. Create a toolbar with custom-button code. The inpage.js should stay unmodified so you can continue to install upgrades. Then if you need it often, create a script which generates the toolbar (there are some examples in the wiki using jQuery)